# Superposition principle in classical collision theory

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, superposition

While reviewing my notes for a test, I stumbled upon a statement which I could not justify. In a diagonal two dimensional collision between a particle and a wall (considering the wall's mass as being much greater than the one of the particle). It is possible to say that the total variation of momentum is given by:

$$\Delta \vec{p} = \vec{p}' - \vec{p} = \left( \vec{p}'_\perp + \vec{p}'_\parallel \right) - \left( \vec{p}_\perp + \vec{p}_\parallel \right)$$

where the components of momentum have been decomposed between the parallel and perpendicular directions to the wall. Since:

$$\vec{p}'_\parallel = \vec{p}_\parallel$$

$$\vec{p}'_\perp = -\vec{p}_\perp$$

the first expression gives:

$$\Delta \vec{p} = -2 \vec{p}_\perp$$

Now, my question is, is it possible to prove that the parallel component of the momentum doesn't change, and that the perpendicular one becomes the opposite of the starting perpendicular component, using the classical superposition principle. That is: "for all linear systems the net response caused by two or more stimuli is the sum of the responses, that would have been caused by each stimulus individually (Wikipedia)". Now, if this principle holds in this case I could say: consider the scenario in which the particle is moving with momentum $\vec{p}_\parallel$, in this scenario the particle doesn't hit the wall, then:

$$\vec{p}'_\parallel = \vec{p}_\parallel$$

Considering the case in which the particle is moving with momentum $\vec{p}_\perp$, I could say that the collision can be studied using a simpler case, the collision between the particle and wall in one dimension (for which I've already proven that it's final momentum is the opposite of the starting momentum), then:

$$\vec{p}'_\perp = -\vec{p}_\perp$$

If these statements are correct, I could reach the conclusion without any other calculation that:

$$\Delta \vec{p} = -2 \vec{p}_\perp$$

Can you please give me a check and tell me if my reasoning could be considered correct? In theory, the algebraic description of this kind of two dimensional collision does agree with the previous description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to draw a free-body diagram of the particle
as it collides with the wall. Presuming a smooth wall, the force by the wall on the particle is perpendicular to the wall's surface.

So, apply Newton's Second Law in component-form, parallel and perpendicular to the wall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I understand that approach, but I would like to know if my method could be used to avoid algebraic calculations and just deduce the behaviour of the particle analysing the motion along the parallel and perpendicular directions.

Comment: @Luke__ Maybe we have a different definition of "algebraic"... but I regard a vectorial calculation as "algebraic"... the algebra of vectors. Forces do satisfy the superposition principle (in fact, forces could be considered the prototype for superposition). So, motions in perpendicular directions are independent and can be superposed.

Comment: Thanks,, all clear now! Besides, what I meant is that with my reasoning even if implied, calculations aren't needed, while writing each force, and then decomposing it, requires "explicit" calculations. But aart from everything I understood, thanks again for your effort!